# Someone please explain this script

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When I run the following code in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <p>Click the button to loop through a block of code five times.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        function myFunction()
        {
            var x="";
            for (var i=0;i<5;i++)
            {
                x = x + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
            }
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It displays the following

```
The number is 0
The number is 1
The number is 2
The number is 3
The number is 4
```

below the "Try it" button when it is clicked. My problem is with this part of the code `x=x + "The number is " + i + "<br>";`. When it is replaced with `x="The number is " + i + "<br>";` it only display

```
 The number is 4
```

. Some please explain why this is so.

Comment: `x += 'The number is '+ i +'<br>'`

Comment: You'd get better help with a good javascript tutorial. By the way, is this homework?

Answer (score 2):

Because x is the string which is displayed.  At each increment of the loop, when the "x" on the right-hand side of the equals sign is kept all the old "The number is " + i + "< br >" are kept as well.  When the "x" on the right-hand side of the equals sign is deleted, the old strings are overwritten to only show the larger number i.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a closure. Inside your for loop, try this script

```
     (function(x, i){
        x=x + "The number is " + i + "<br>";
     })(x, i);
```